# Understanding how transaction.complete function?

Tags: c#, distributed-transactions

Hi All we have started to use transaction scope and below is the code snippet. What we need to understand is based on our understading after each of the using for connection the particular connection will be disposed/closed right? So since its closed how does the transaction.complete works?

```
using (TransactionScope transScope = new TransactionScope())
{
   try
   {
      string myConnStringLocal = "User Id=***;Password=****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingLocalIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingLocalDB;
      using (MySqlConnection connectionLocal = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringLocal))
      {
         try{
         connectionLocal.Open();
         }
         Catch(Exception e)
         {

         }
         finally{
         connectionLocal.Close();
         }
      }

      string myConnStringCentral = "User Id=***;Password=*****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingCentralIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingCentralDB;
      using (MySqlConnection connectionCentral = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringCentral))
      {
         try{
         connectionCentral.Open();
         }
         Catch(Exception e)
         {

         }
         finally{
         connectionCentral.Close();
         }

      }
      string myConnStringCentralCopy = "User Id=*****;Password=*****;Host=" + globalSettings.settingCentralCopyIP + ";Database=" + globalSettings.settingCentralCopyDB;
      using (MySqlConnection connectionCentralCopy = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringCentralCopy))
      {
         try{
         connectionCentralCopy.Open();
         }
         Catch(Exception e)
         {

         }
         finally{
         connectionCentralCopy.Close();
         }
      }
      transScope.Complete();
      Console.WriteLine("Transaction is completed");
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Transaction is rolled back");
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to actually run the code and see what happened?

Comment: @Yes I tried the transaction works but I would like to learn the details of it.

Answer (score 7):

`TransactionScope.Complete` tells all of the Transaction Managers that they are good to commit this transaction. It is not a guarantee that everything will actually commit. After the ***Complete*** method is called all the transaction managers initiate a commit individually and if all of the transaction Managers succeed then the transaction is considered as completed successfully.
You may refer to this [link for further details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope)

Comment: @So my ultimate thing how to guarenteee that all will commit? I mean how to ensure the integrity of distributed transaction in these case ? So after each of the using end isnt the connection is closed so how will it invoke the connection then ?

Comment: You can never guarantee commit. The purpose of the transaction is not to guarantee that everything will but to guarantee that either everything will commit or nothing will commit.

Comment: @So its guaratee that there wont be either one commit it will be either all commit or not commit at all right. So how about the connection availability after the using block ?

Comment: @YK1 has a pretty good explanation about connection avalibility.

Answer (score 4):

When you connect to multiple databases in a single `TransactionScope`, the transaction is escalated to a `distributed` transaction and coordinated by `MSDTC` using [2-phase commit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit).

Regarding connection close - this is special case when connection is closed inside a `TransactionScope`, internally it is managed by `System.Transactions` infrastructure, so db session may still be open even though connection closed from your end.

See this note on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx):

> Pending transactions started using Transact-SQL or BeginTransaction are automatically rolled back when the connection is reset if connection pooling is enabled. If connection pooling is off, the transaction is rolled back after SqlConnection.Close is called. Transactions started through System.Transactions are controlled through the System.Transactions infrastructure, and are not affected by SqlConnection.Close

**EDIT** Based on your comments, here is what you can do:

```
try
{
   using (TransactionScope transScope = new TransactionScope())
   {
      string myConnStringLocal = ...;
      using (var connectionLocal = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringLocal))
      {
         connectionLocal.Open();
         // do your DB update 

      } //no need to close connection explicitly, the using() {..} statement does that for you

      string myConnStringCentral = ...;
      using (var connectionCentral = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringCentral))
      {
         connectionCentral.Open();
         // do your DB update

      } //no need to close connection explicitly, the using() {..} statement does that for you

      string myConnStringCentralCopy = ...;
      using (var connectionCentralCopy = new MySqlConnection(myConnStringCentralCopy))
      {         
         connectionCentralCopy.Open();
         // do your DB update

      } //no need to close connection explicitly, the using() {..} statement does that for you

      transScope.Complete();

      Console.WriteLine("Transaction is completed");

   } //no need to dispose transactionScope explicitly, the using() {..} statement does that for you
}
catch (Exception)
{
      // If any exception occurs in the try block above transScope.Complete() line will be caught here
      // and will automatically cause the transaction to rollback.
      Console.WriteLine("Transaction is rolled back");
}

// You can then start new TransactionScope if you want to further update more than one DB in a transactional manner.
try
{
   using (TransactionScope transScope = new TransactionScope())
   {
      //...

   }
}
catch (Exception)
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: yes this was what I am looking cause if you see my question I have further updated it with the try and catch and finally to close the connections individually. IS that fine? Can you review the codes in my question with is it right to do that ?

Comment: @new14: there is no need to explicitly close connection in `finally` block if you have `using( .. myconn... ) { .. } ` - because the `using` statement compiles to a `try/finally` block and calls `Dipose` on the connection in the finally block automatically - `Dispose` inturn will call `Close`.

Comment: Where is the compilcation of the try/finally is it in the background as we dont see it right? I am not clear much here please describe further.

Comment: @new14: please understand how the `using` statement works. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C In your case connection object's `Dispose()` will call its `Close()` so you don't have to call it explicitly.

Comment: @new14: the codeproject article I have linked above has one minor mistake - it says `The CLR converts your code into MSIL` which is not correct. Its actually the C# compiler who does it.

Comment: you are right I notice if I put the extra try and catch and finally I get this sort of errors "Object reference not set to an instance of an object? So based on the article in case there is any error how will it be highlighted then ? So I understand that the try catch is done in the background so no chance to have our own error message in the catch right?

Comment: @new14: `using` is not `try/catch` - it is `try/finally`. There is no `catch`. It `Disposes` the connection in `finally` which is automatically generated by `using`. You can have your own `try/catch` to handle errors. You just don't need to have an explicit `finally` to close the connection as `using` does that for you.

Comment: @new14: I think you may have not understood `using` statement properly. Forget transactions for a moment and try to play around `using` statement, `try/catch`, `try/finally`, `IDisposable` etc. IF you dont understand open new `question`. This is probably not right `question` to discuss about it.

Comment: ok I am getting it I have removed the inner try and catch and finally in the using it works fine with the error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object?. I have one more problem after I called the transScope.Complete(); and immediately in I called another function say to populate a grid it gives me error saying The current TransactionScope is already complete. where the new connection is supposed to be a new one not linked to the transaction which is already completed?

Comment: I notice the solution is that that immediately after the transScope.Complete(); if I call transScope.Dispose(); and then I call any other function from there it does not give me any error I guess this the right way to do it?

Comment: @new14: error is correct - there should be no more db related statements in a transactionScope after its Completed. Again, you have used `using(... transScope..) { .. }` - so no need to call ` transScope.Dispose()` explicitly as `using` does that for you. If you want to start new batch of distributed transaction then start a new TrasanctionScope block.

Comment: what I want to do is that once the transaction.complete is sucessfully I want to call another function which will update the grid also another function to generate a crystal report document. So how to go about that ?

Comment: @new14: you should open new question for that and show us what difficulty you have with it.

Comment: ok I have created a new question to get the determination if it works as what I have done.

Answer (score 2):

When the `Complete` method is called, then everything in the scope will be committed, if no `Exception` is thrown. If the code gets out of scope without `Complete`, then no commit will occur. In short, if you call the `Complete` method, then, in case there are no `Exceptions` thrown, your transaction(s) in the scope of the given `TransactionScope` will be committed.

Also, I must add, that there might also be a hierarchy, a tree of `TransactionScopes`. You can also set the behavior of a `TransactionScope` for the case when a sub-scope of the `TransactionScope` rolled back.